# Facebook comments plugin not working on iOS Safari

Tags: ios, facebook, plugins, safari, comments

I am trying to implement the FB comments plugin (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) on a website. It's loading fine, but on iOS Safari the user cannot click into the comments field. When trying to click into the field, a quick visual glitch happens, and then focus is lost.

On some phones, if I log into facebook in the same browser, this makes an alert appear, when clicking into the field, to allow facebook tracking. After accepting that I'm allowed to click into the field.

I haven't managed to find any info on this. It's working fine on desktop/laptop macs and PCs, android and in iOS Chrome. But specifically in iOS Safari (on some phones) it's bugging out.

Does anyone know anything about this bug and how to fix it?

Comment: That is likely directly related to the tracker blocking, it either blocks loading a relevant script file, or any of the cookies Facebook needs to check whether there’s a logged-in user. There probably aren’t any other options, than to tell users they need to deactivate this feature, if they want this to work.

Comment: Thanks for your input @CBroe

I was able to test it on one of the iphones that had the bug, and it seems that settings -> safari -> prevent cross-site tracking has something to say in this. When disabling that, the comments field is auto un-focused after the first click, but then you can click into it afterwards. Still is still pretty buggy.

Any idea why the alert appears on some phones while not on others?

Answer (score 1):

It's the settings -> safari -> Hide IP Address (from trackers) switch that stops the FB plugins working!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).